# Deleting an item from my shopping cart using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, variables, unset

I'm just learning how to use this StackOverflow, so please bear with me. If you need anything further I can provide it. I can click the checkmark on your answer if you can help me.

My code is working, but there is a small glitch. Currently, I have $i=0 and my code deletes the $i from the form. The problem is that with, for example, when $i=2 is deleted, $i=3 becomes $i=2, and I can no longer delete that item from my cart, because it is now the same $i that was deleted.

Here is my code:

```
     if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove'] != "") {
    // Access the array and run code to remove that array index
    $key_to_remove = $_POST['index_to_remove'];
    if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1) {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
        header("location: cart.php");
        } else {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["$key_to_remove"]);
        //sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    }
}
```

And here is my output loop:

```
$cartoutput = "";
$cartTotal="";
$totalwithtaxdisplay = 0;
$servicechargedisplay =0;
$grandtotaldisplay = 0;
if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1){
    $cartoutput = "<div align='center'><font style='font-weight: bold; font-size: 20pt;'>Your order is currently empty.</font></div>";
}else{
    $i=0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menuitem WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
            if (!$result) {
            printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));// Displays the error that mysql will generate if syntax is not correct.
            exit();
            }
            //echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                //item id is $each_item['item_id']; being pulled in from form on other page PID.
                $id = $row['id'];       
                $product_name = $row["name"];
                $price = $row["price"]; 
                $description = $row['description'];             
        }
            $tax = .065;
            $service = .18;
            $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
            $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
            $totalwithtax = round($cartTotal + ($cartTotal * $tax), 2); //Order Items + Tax
            $totalwithtaxdisplay = number_format($totalwithtax, 2, '.', '');        //displays the decimals correctly
            $servicecharge = round($totalwithtax * $service, 2); //service charge
            $servicechargedisplay = number_format($servicecharge, 2, '.', '');      //displays the decimals correctly
            $grandtotal = round($totalwithtax + ($totalwithtax * $service), 2); //service charge
            $grandtotaldisplay = number_format($grandtotal, 2, '.', '');    //displays the decimals correctly           

            $cartoutput .= " <tr><td width='20%'> Order Item $i </td> 
                            <td width='40%'>  " . $product_name . "</td>
                            <td width='20%'> $" . $price . ".00</td>";

            $cartoutput .=" <td width='20%'><form action='cart.php' method='post'>
                            <input name='deleteBtn" . $item_id . "'type='submit' value='Remove This Item' />
                            <input name='index_to_remove' type='hidden' value='" . $i . "' />   
                            </form></td></tr>";
            $i++;

    }
}
```

I echo out the $cartouput at a later time. You can see in the code above the second $cartouput is the form i'm using. It hold the value $i, but when that value is deleted, it doesn't let me delete the item that has updated into the new $i.

Comment: can you post your output loop?

Comment: Why did you remove the important parts from your code?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to post it correctly. It should be updated now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `index_to_remove` to `$i`, you should set it to `$item_id` and in your session variable. That way, you no longer need `$i`.

Also, this line leaves you with an SQL injection vulnerability: `$item_id = $each_item['item_id'];`. You should, at minimum, escape it using [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string).

Comment: I will take a look at that, thank you. Could you provide an example for me?